# Google BigQuery: SELECT with destination table overrides field modes to NULLABLE

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm writing a tool to update my bigquery tables to reflect my locally defined schemas. Let's say I'm updating the table `users`. The steps for doing this are:

1. Create a new table with the new schema, called `users_update`.
2. Create a `SELECT` query where values are cast (e.g. TIMESTAMP to DATETIME), and new columns added (e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as date_updated`)
3. Run a QueryJob (python) to execute the query with the new table as the destination.
4. Delete the table `users`
5. Copy `users_update` to `users`
6. Delete the table `users_update`

The problem is that this query converts every field in the new table to `NULLABLE`. I've stepped through my script, and I've verified that the new table has correct modes before the QueryJob. I also provide the new schema (with correct modes) to the QueryJob.

Are there some parameters to the QueryJob I need to set, or what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share some of your python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had set the `job_config.write_disposition` to `WRITE_TRUNCATE`. Removing this solved my issue.